# Python 2.7: I can't remove worksheets using xlwt.Workbook._Workbook__worksheets

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I have a workbook containing 12 sheets. I want to create a new file deleting 7 of them.
However I can't get rid of "OLD FILES", "Licencias" and "HTM". [Here is a sample of the workbook,](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2AYlge_EK89R3RBVlZDc2NQdWc/edit?usp=sharing) and here is my code. Please help me find out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
import xlrd, xlwt, xlutils.copy

#open the report, assign it to a variable
reporteWilly = xlrd.open_workbook('cctable.xls')

#create a writable copy of the report.
reporteWillyBk = xlutils.copy.copy(reporteWilly)

#Delete the sheets I dont want in the file
#by accessing the internal of the object xlwt.Workbook._Workbook_worksheets
#and there I'll specify only the elements I want in the sheets list:

#First I create a list of the worksheets available
okSheets = reporteWillyBk._Workbook__worksheets

#Then I remove from the list the sheets I don't want.
for sheet in okSheets:
    if (sheet.name == "Guayaquil" or sheet.name== "Exports" or sheet.name == "OLD FILES" 
        or sheet.name == "Ecuador Holidays 2011" or sheet.name == "Licencias"
        or sheet.name == "FILE LOCATION" or sheet.name == "HTM" ):

        okSheets.remove(sheet)

#lastly I assing the good sheets I want to the collection.
reporteWillyBk._Workbook__worksheets = okSheets

#and save the new workbook.
reporteWillyBk.save ('cctableWilly.xls')
```

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't be modifying variables that have been flagged as private by starting the variable name with an underscore, so this line `reporteWillyBk._Workbook__worksheets = okSheets` looks pretty suspect. Does your `reporteWillyBk` object have a `remove_sheet()` or `delete_sheet()` method that you can use?

Comment: Hi Marius, unfortunately the xlwt.Worbook object does not have any remove_sheet or delete_sheet methods.

Answer (score 1):

I've a good experience using `openpyxl` to do this

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('/path/to/your/workbook.xls')

print wb.get_sheet_names() #do this to double check your asking for the right sheet names

bad_sheets = ["Guayaquil","Exports","OLD FILES" ,"Ecuador Holidays 2011","Licencias","FILE LOCATION","HTM"]

#now delete the bad sheets
[wb.remove_sheet(wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)) for sheet in bad_sheets]
#if you get a ValueError, this means you are incorrectly requesting a sheet

wb.save('/some/other/name.xls')
```

Good luck, I hope this helps

Comment: You shouldn't use a list comprehension if you don't want to build a list of values with it.